# NodeJS checking for function completion before proceeding

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have a question regarding the asynchronous method APIs in Node.

So, I have a function, let's call it `longSetup(callback)`.

As the name suggests, `longSetup(callback)` takes a long time to complete. However, this setup can be done in parallel with other things. So, while `longSetup()` is happening, I can have other things being setup as well.

So once `longSetup()` is done, that class is ready to execute another function, such as `serveData()`.

Now, I don't know when `serveData()` will be invoked. `serveData()` is based on user I/O, and may be invoked before `longSetup()` finishes, or may be invoked after `longSetup()` finishes. Also, I never directly invoke `serveData()`.

It's true that I need `longSetup()` to be completed before `serveData()` can be executed successfully, but I'd like to capitalize on the fact that `longSetup()` can be done asynchronously, and thus I don't want to implement a synchronous version of `longSetup()`; I'd rather have other setup being done during that time.

Since `serveData()` can be called anytime, I'd like to check if `longSetup()` is completed when `serveData()` is invoked. If it completed, proceed with `serveData()`. If not, wait till `longSetup()` is done and then proceed with execution. Since `longSetup()` is invoked only once, I won't be waiting in most cases. Also, if user I/O takes time, `longSetup()` would be done by the time `serveData()` is invoked for the first time as well.

I've been through a couple of SO questions and answers regarding waiting for a function to return before executing another function/firing one function after another function etc. and I understand the asynchronous way of Node and why to use callbacks. However, this is a different use case and I was wondering if node provides some way of waiting on another asynchronous function.

Thanks all!

Comment: call serveData() from the bottom of longSetup()

Comment: Toggle a boolean when `longSetup` finishes and check for it inside `serveData` before preceding with the rest of the function?

Comment: Have you looked into promises?  https://github.com/kriskowal/q seems to be popular.

Comment: @dandavis Thanks but that use case is different from mine. As the question states, I don't invoke `serveData()` directly.

Comment: You might meet some state management here. The simplest one would be have a boolean variable `ready` set to false on startup and, the callback of `longSetup` can set it to true when triggered.
In the mean while, use a sort of buffer/stack/array/whatever to store all the calls of `serveData()` while `longSetup` is performing.
The callback will then unempty that buffer/stack/array/whatever and serve them.

Comment: @thgaskell , @CBlanchard and @MarcoCI That's what I was thinking - to toggle a boolean once `longSetup()` finishes. However, when I enter `serveData()`, I'll need to either poll if the flag is set, or implement some queue by myself. Is there a Node provided API that I might be missing?

Comment: ok, then at the end of longSetup, say longSetup.ok=1; in the top of serveData: if(!longSetup.ok){return setTimeout(serveData, 100);} use an anon to push args to the differed serveData() if needed.

Comment: @dandavis Ah - cool. That's sort of like polling. That's actually what I'm implementing now, just wondering if they had something like "asyc_wait". But thanks though! :D At least I know I'm heading in the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@arturgrzesiak's answer was calling `serveData` from `longSetup` and had no way to delay execution of `serveData` until `longSetup` was complete. ***edit*** upon reading his answer more closely it looks like i'm mistaken, and `serveData` would be called once at the end of `longSetup`. however my solution should allow `serveData` to be called multiple times if e.g. multiple users request data during setup.

```
var setupFinished = false;

var longSetup = function() {
    ...
    // at end:
    setupFinished = true;
}

var serveDataWrapper = function(query){
  if(!setupFinished){
    setTimeout(
      function(){
        serveDataWrapper(query);
      },
      200 //ms
    );
  } else { // setup is finished
    serveData(query);
  };
}

var serveData = function (query) {
  // longSetup is now guranteed to be complete
};

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  serveDataWrapper(req.query['query']);
});
```

Comment: I'm marking this answer as correct because it does provide **a** solution to going about the effect that I'm looking to achieve. Also, as pointed out by everyone, there is nothing natively provided by NodeJS for this effect. However, if you (@Plato), or anybody else, comes up with an updated answer (maybe because there's a new API in the future), I'll also update the answer accordingly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be a suitable solution for you:

```
var setupInfo = { serveData : false, setupFinished : false }

var longSetup = function() {

    ...

    // at the very bottom
    if (setupInfo.serveData) {
        serveData();
    }
    setupInfo.setupFinished = true }
}

var serveData = function () {
    // at the very top
    if (!setupInfo.setupFinished){
         setupInfo.serveData = true;
         return;
    }

    ... 
}
```

In case you want to serveData multiple times you have to keep a counter instead of simple `bool`.

---

Do not think node.js provide some API for your task, but there are for sure external libraries to deal with this problem, that are based on the `promise pattern`. 
[Here](http://howtonode.org/promises) is some rather oldish, but still useful article on this topic.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, I won't be invoking `serveData()`. `serveData()` will be invoked as a result of some user I/O. That being said, in the `serveData()` implementation, I wish to wait for the bool till it's set and then proceed. I can poll the bool or implement my own queue, but I'm wondering whether Node is already providing an API for the same.

Comment: Updated the the code to make it specific that what I mean was function declarations. When and by whom it will be called it does not matter much, but still it will provide the synchronization you needed.

Comment: yup if you insist on allowing calls to `serveData` before the completion callback of `longSetup` is called, then the only solution I am aware of is keeping track of the state in a globally scoped variable as @arturgrzesiak suggests in this answer